# How to: Find The Name of a Symbolic Link

Tags: files, symlink, rm

I made a symbolic link with `ln -s /home/orca/www/* /var/` and now I need to delete it.  I needed to move all my webfiles which were in `/var/www` to `/home` because my `/` was full.  [Here is what I did](https://paste.linux.community/view/3b405763).

I see from [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-symbolic-links-in-linux/) that I simply `rm symlink_name` but what exactly is the name?

```
rm /home/orca/www/*                           ?
```

I tend to get things backwards even though I've read many articles because I am unorthodox by nature.  This is a live production server so I am proceeding with caution before taking action.  Less is more.  I'd rather be safe then sorry.  Backups are in place.

Comment: You may have made multiple symlinks with that command. Instead of blindly removing them (which may also remove other files), run first a `find /var -lname '/home/orca/*' -ls` and then, **if all that should go**, replace the `-ls` with `-exec rm {} +`.

Comment: The output worked. What does -exec mean? Execute? What do you mean by {} ? So would the command be this "find /var/ -lname '/home/orca/*' -exec rm {} +"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation in [man ln](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html).

You used the 3rd form

```
ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY
```

which will create links for all *TARGET*s in *DIRECTORY*.

Your command has created (or tried to create) links for all files and directories (and other objects if any) in `/home/orca/www`, **but** it may have failed for some of them if the name already existed in `/var`. (Your command may have printed error messages in this case.)

As `/var` is normally not empty you cannot simply remove everything.

The best I can suggest now is to remove all names that are present in `/home/orca/www` from `/var` if it is a symbolic link there.

This loop will show what would be removed:

```
for i in /home/orca/www/*
do
    l=/var/"${i##*/}"
    if [ -h "$l" ]
    then
        echo rm "$l"
    fi
done
```

**Check the output.** If this is what you want, remove the `echo` to really execute the `rm` commands.

```
for i in /home/orca/www/*
do
    l=/var/"${i##*/}"
    if [ -h "$l" ]
    then
        rm "$l"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Perfect! Am I supposed to mark you as the correct answer somehow?

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`,

```
rm /var/*(@m-1)
```

Would remove all the symlinks in `/var` that have been created in the last 24 hours.

While:

```
rm /var/*(@m-1e['[[ $REPLY:P = /home/orca/www/* ]]'])
```

would remove all the symlinks created in the last 24 hours whose *real path* (canonical absolute path) matches the `/home/orca/www/*` pattern (would not work properly if `/home`, `/home/orca`, `/home/orca/www` or any of the files in there are themselves symlinks).

(replace `rm` with `ls -ld` if you just want to see the list before removing the files).

With GNU `find`, you can also do:

```
find /var -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -lname '/home/orca/www/*' -delete
```

To remove all the symlinks in `/var` created in the last 24 hours whose target matches the `/home/orca/www/*` pattern.

(replace `-delete` with `-ls` if you want to see the list before removing the files)